# How to use JavaScript variable as a param on @Messages

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

Is it possible to use a JS variable inside `@Messages` as a parameter? When I use this, I get the following error:

> not found: value name

```
var name = "some name";
var title = "@Messages("message", name)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, `@Messages` compiled on the server and javascript on the client. It will compile before javascript even if you will pre-compile it with some server side js engine.

Here is special module to compute messages on client side, but I am not sure it is still relevant for Play 2.5:

https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use server data or variables in your JS code, you could use this approach. In some situations, I need my JS to have a list of server items, so in my whatever.scala.html, I create a script tag and initialize a JS variable from the server like below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  // get employee data from our server model - it needs to be converted to JSON for JS
  var employeeJsonString = @{Html(new Gson().toJson(model.getEmployeesAsJson()))};
  var employees = JSON.parse(exmployeeJsonString);
  // then you may use employees in JS code...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsMessages is a good solution.

If you want a more generic solution for any kind of code, not just messages, you can try out this: [JavascriptRouting](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting)

It enables you to pass javascript variables to any call to an endpoint in your application. But true, you would have to set up a Play route for your Messages.